# How to set the hostname using only the standard library?

Tags: rust, hostname

Does the Rust standard library offer the possibility to set a machine's hostname? Or do I need to make a system call and set it via the `hostname` command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rust standard library does not provide such function. Moreover, the methods for setting hostname differ across operating systems, so there is no portable way. You can probably make a crate to set the hostname portably and publish it on crates.io, in case someone else would need it.